# "select_none" button of datatables is not working as expected in multi select mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the jquery plugin Datatables from [here](http://www.datatables.net/).

The problem is that it doesn't behavior like it should. I have 2 buttons in the TableTools, Select all and Select none, both have the default code behind them I havn't changed a thing with them.

I also made the rows multi selectable. Here is the code of the declaration of the datatables and pretty much everything that matters.

```
var oTable;
var gaiSelected =  [];
oTable = $('#listeLigne').dataTable({
                "sDom": 'T',
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "oLanguage": oLanguage,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "iDisplayLength": -1,
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath" : "<?= _s("js/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf") ?>",
                    "aButtons": [
                        {
                            "sExtends":    "collection",
                            "sButtonText": "Sélection",
                            "aButtons": [ 
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "select_all",
                                    "sButtonText": "Toutes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "text",
                                    "sButtonText": "Actives"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "text",
                                    "sButtonText": "Inactives"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "text",
                                    "sButtonText": "Suspendues"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "select_none",
                                    "sButtonText": "Aucune"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "sExtends":    "collection",
                            "sButtonText": "Sauvegarder",
                            "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                        },
                        {
                            "sExtends":    "print",
                            "sButtonText": "Imprimer"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                    if ( jQuery.inArray(aData[0], gaiSelected) != -1 )
                    {
                        $(nRow).addClass('row_selected');
                    }
                    return nRow;
                }
            });

$('#listeLigne tbody tr').live('click', function () {
                var aData = oTable.fnGetData( this );
                var iId = aData[0];

                if ( jQuery.inArray(iId, gaiSelected) == -1 )
                {
                    gaiSelected[gaiSelected.length++] = iId;
                }
                else
                {
                    gaiSelected = jQuery.grep(gaiSelected, function(value) {
                        return value != iId;
                    } );
                }

                $(this).toggleClass('DTTT_selected');
            } );
```

What happens is if I click select all, it selects them all, and then if I click select none, it does unselect everything. However if I click some of them and make them selected, and then press select none, nothing happens. And then if I do press select all and then select none it does work.

I have been looking at the internal code of datatables, tried many different solutions from around the web (even though I have not seen many folks with the same problem).

Request any other information you might need.
Every bit of information and/or help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I replaced the code above for this:

```
oTable = $('#listeLigne').dataTable({
                "sDom": 'T',
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "oLanguage": oLanguage,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "iDisplayLength": -1,
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sRowSelect": "multi",
                    "sSwfPath" : "<?= _s("js/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf") ?>",
                    "aButtons": [
                        {
                                    "sExtends":    "select_none",
                                    "sButtonText": "Aucune"
                                },
                        {
                            "sExtends":    "collection",
                            "sButtonText": "Sélection",
                            "aButtons": [ 
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "select_all",
                                    "sButtonText": "Toutes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "text",
                                    "sButtonText": "Actives"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "text",
                                    "sButtonText": "Inactives"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "text",
                                    "sButtonText": "Suspendues"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "select_none",
                                    "sButtonText": "Aucune"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "sExtends":    "collection",
                            "sButtonText": "Sauvegarder",
                            "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                        },
                        {
                            "sExtends":    "print",
                            "sButtonText": "Imprimer"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });

$('#listeLigne tbody tr').live('click', function () {
                var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance('listeLigne');
                oTT.fnSelect(this);
            } );
```

So basically, the first one is using the methods found by searching Google "datatables select rows" which gives you the standard way of doing it. However since I'm using TableTools it's different. In that case one must use the API of TableTools.

Note that the .live function is not complete as it will only select, but you get what I mean.

The documentation of DataTables is very complete, but hard to find things sometimes and sometimes out of date.